# Differences between gmaps and gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I am able to show my markers when I use this:

```
<%= gmaps4rails(@my_json_data) %>
```

However, if I just change that line for this one:

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => { "data" => @my_json_data }) %>
```

And **@my_json_data** value is:

```
@my_json_data = '[{"description":"test","lat":"37.564486","lng":"-122.323672"}]'
```

The map is not focused where I have the marker(s). I have to zoom out and check where those are. When I zoom out, I can see the map duplicated horizontally too. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gmaps4rails` is just a convenient shortcut for `gmaps` with some default options.

[See source code](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/new_gen/lib/gmaps4rails/helper/gmaps4rails_helper.rb).

Horizontally duplicated map is the default behavior of google maps depending on your map size and zoom level.

Comment: But, is there any reason why it should not be focused where my markers are?

Comment: yes: some people prefer having the map centered where the user lives.

Comment: I guess, I will have to look into the options I need to pass to gmaps. By default gmaps4rails focus on the markers, that's why I got confused.